# Parsing http responses in Elm 0.18

Tags: parsing, elm

I am parsing http responses from my server (Phoenix 1.3) on my Elm 0.18 frontend.

The response looks like this:

```
error: BadStatus { status = { code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity" }, headers = Dict.fromList [("cache-control","max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"),("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8")], url = "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/sessions", body = "{\"error\":\"No user could be found\"}" }
```

I would like to extract the three-digit HTTP code as a String....in this case, "422".

What is the best way to parse this in Elm?  I am using a very hacky method and I'd like to know what tools are best applied here.

```
    errorCode : String -> String
      errorCode =
        error
            |> Debug.log "error"
            |> toString
            |> String.split "code = "
            |> List.drop 1
            |> String.join ""
            |> String.split ","
            |> List.take 1
            |> String.join ""
            |> Debug.log "Error"
```

Comment: What would you like the output look like?

Comment: Given that the response is (almost) valid Elm, you might be able to leverage an existing parser.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Edited, I want the code "422" as a string

Comment: How about `dropWhile isNotDigit >> takeWhile isDigit`? Or you could just use drop, assuming the stuff before the number is always the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an [`Error`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest/Http#Error) from the `elm-lang/http` package.  The string you quoted is just how `Error`s are rendered as strings in the console / debugger, I believe -- I don't think there's any parsing to be done, as such.

In other words, I think the function you want doesn't operate on `String`s at all:

```
errorCode : Error -> Maybe String
errorCode err =
    case err of
        BadStatus response ->
            Just response.status.code

        _ ->
            Nothing
```

(The elm compiler should of course tell you whether your `String -> String` or my `Error -> Maybe String` signature is correct.)